# Sorting dataframe by group with the help of a reference list

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe in R that has a nested structure. I want to sort the dataframe by group (based on ID and Year). I have a reference dataframe, which provides me with guidance on how to sort the dataframe. The reference dataframe is based on an existing dataframe with the same structure as the unsorted dataframe. Below is the sample nested dataframe and the sample reference list:

```
ID Year Location Note
1  2000 LA       West Coast
1  2000 Boston   East Coast
1  2000 SF       West Coast
1  2001 Boston   East Coast
1  2001 LA       West Coast
2  1998 SF       West Coast
2  1999 Atlanta  East Coast
2  1999 NYC      East Coast
```

Reference dataframe:

```
ID          Location
1           LA
1           Miami
1           Boston
1           Salt Lake City
1           NYC
2           NYC
2           Atlanta
```

As mentioned, the reference dataframe is based on an existing dataframe with the same structure as the unsorted dataframe. The problem with the reference dataframe is that it does not necessarily foresee all the combinations of Location in the unsorted dataframe as there can be new combinations. For ID-Year in the unsorted dataframe that cannot find a reference, I want a new variable "Sort" with value 0 to indicate they are not being sorted. So the ideal output is:

```
ID Year Location Note        Sort 
1  2000 LA       West Coast  0
1  2000 Boston   East Coast  0
1  2000 SF       West Coast  0
1  2001 LA       West Coast  1
1  2001 Boston   East Coast  1
2  1998 SF       West Coast  1
2  1999 NYC      East Coast  1
2  1999 Atlanta  East Coast  1
```

Note we can assume the rank in the reference is consistent (i.e., if Boston is above LA, it will be above LA in the reference across all IDs).